# Open files in different software based on file signature (not extension) in Windows

Tags: windows, file-format, signature

Is there any software for opening files with the same extension in different software depending on the file's signature?

For example, a file with extension `.pcb` and file signature `PCB FILE 4` should be opened in one program, while a file with extension `.pcb` and file signature `00 FF` should be opened in an entirely different program.

I made my own solution a while ago, which I will post as an answer, but it's annoying and clunky to use, and maybe there's some obscure general-purpose dedicated compiled solution out there that works better.

Comment: You could write a wrapper around TrID https://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html

Answer (score 0):

Before Software Recommendations existed, I posted the same question on SuperUser, and ended up solving it myself with a python script:

https://superuser.com/a/317927/13889

which is now here:

https://gist.github.com/endolith/1119561

But it's annoying to configure.